# parsing XML gives me a list of slurpersupport attributes but I want a list of texts

Tags: xml, url, file-io, groovy, xmlslurper

I fetch an xml file from the internet using a URL

```
def url = "http://www.kth.se/api/kopps/v1/course/DD1390/round/2014:2/1".toURL()
InputStream inp = url.openStream()
def kursomgXML = new XmlSlurper().parse(inp).declareNamespace(xml:'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace')
```

I used the following :

```
courseRound.courseResponsibleList.courseResponsible.@primaryEmail.list()
```

which seemed to work fine but when using the result in a method call I get an error saying that no signature of the method is applicable on a value of type groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attribute

How do I get a list of strings instead of a list of slurpersupport attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call `.text()` on the attribute to get a string. or e.g. spread (`*.`) it over the list

```
courseRound.courseResponsibleList.courseResponsible.list().'@primaryEmail'*.text()
```